# Summing up MySQL calculated field where column value is the same

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, self-join

Basically, I am trying to sum up the value of a calculated field when a certain value (in my case COMMUNICATIONS_ID) are equal. These scores are associated with the same COMMUNICATIONS_ID and I want to sum up these values.

I am new to SQL and this is my misguided first attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM consumer_action_log as cal1
JOIN consumer_action_log as cal2
    ON cal1.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cal2.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
    AND cal1.COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

Comment: What is the field/column name you wish to sum?  Also, what is the primary key for the table?  Posting the CREATE TABLE statement would really help, possibly some example data too.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to sum?

Comment: Are you trying to sum records for comm_type_id's other than 4, based on those who have 4 associated?  If not, there's no need for the self join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COMMUNICATIONS_ID, SUM(fieldName) 
FROM consumer_action_log
WHERE COMM_TYPE_ID = 4
GROUP BY COMMUNICATIONS_ID
```

I don't see a need to JOIN the table to itself here.

Comment: See comment against my answer

Comment: I agree, I don't see the need but the OP needs to clarify before I vote for anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to split the ON and WHERE conditions, even if the result is the same for INNER JOINs.  Makes it clearer what links the two tables.

```
SELECT sum(cal2.somecolumn)
FROM consumer_action_log as cal1
JOIN consumer_action_log as cal2
    ON cal1.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cal2.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
WHERE cal1.COMM_TYPE_ID=4
```

- Find cal1 records where `COMM_TYPE_ID=4`
- Join to cal2 (self join) where the COMMUNICATIONS_ID is equal to cal1
- Sum up some column from cal2

If the filter on `COMMS_TYPE_ID=4` results in multiple `cal1.COMMUNICATIONS_ID`s, then you will want to `GROUP BY` COMMUNICATIONS_ID (doesn't matter from cal1 or cal2 - they are the same)

```
SELECT cal2.COMMUNICATIONS_ID, sum(cal2.somecolumn)
FROM consumer_action_log as cal1
JOIN consumer_action_log as cal2
    ON cal1.COMMUNICATIONS_ID=cal2.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
WHERE cal1.COMM_TYPE_ID=4
GROUP BY cal2.COMMUNICATIONS_ID
```

Comment: Self-join: to get other records of the same COMMUNICATIONS_ID but different COMM_TYPE_ID `associated with the same COMMUNICATIONS_ID`

Comment: Valid, I just don't see the requirement from the OP.  It might change things if that's not the case.

Comment: @cyberwiki: Good point. So it's up to the OP to decide which answer fits.